# Magento Magmi import products CSV reindex not working

Tags: magento-1.9, import, reindex, magmi

I've used `Magmi` to **import** `bulk products` to `Magento Store` and all fine but when the import finishes the reindex plugin `( Magmi Magento Reindexer v1.0.3a)` not working I've to use PHP CLI command `php-cli`, plus I've enabled `On the fly indexer v0.2` plugin but still not working.

**So any suggestions about that please ?**

Comment: Did you try to reindex from admin ?

Comment: Yes but in my store i have big number of products so i want to reindex after importing directly if possible without try that from admin.

Comment: Than try to execute reindex command from magento root directory.Magmi directly insert prroduct in DB, if you have checked magmi fires direct SQL queries, so you need to indexing to show products at frontend.

Comment: i've try that and it's working perfectly but in my case the importing is daily and the reindex is mandatory after each importing about 2 times each day.

Comment: Than simply set php script with reindex command to cron. set cron as per you need.

Comment: Okay it's clear, but i want to understand if `Magmi` reindex working or not please and why not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63307/discussion-between-developer-webile-and-mahmoudismail).

Answer (score 3):

First thing, try entering 'php-cli' into the **PHP CLI command** field.

If you're running Magmi using a browser, the indexer may fail due to a few possible reasons.

1. Reindexing the **catalog_url** and **catalog_category_product** indexes can take a very long time for a site with a lot of products.  If the amount of time exceeds the timeout limit set on PHP, the script will stop running prematurely and not fully reindex the site.  For this reason the [On the fly indexer](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=On_the_fly_indexer) was created so these indexes would be handled as items are imported/updated.
2. If you're receiving the error `This script cannot be run from Browser. This is the shell script.`, this is because the **/shell/abstract.php** file prevents the indexer.php file from being run from the browser.  A temporary fix would be to open up **/shell/abstract.php**, look for `die('This script cannot be run from Browser. This is the shell script.');` and commenting it out.
3. Last resort, try running your index process using a SSH connection by running the following command: `php indexer.php reindexall`.  Wait to see if everything completes without error. (Note, you must first `cd` into the `/shell` directory before running the indexer command.)

   I hope It's helpful for figure out.